# How to authorize BreezeController webapi call

Tags: breeze

I created a new MVC4 Application and install nuget package Breeze.MVC4WebApiClientSample

Inside the BreezeSampleController, i added an "Authorize" attribute. When i browse to here
`http://localhost:XXXXX/api/BreezeSample/todos`, i can still see the data.

How can i authorize the call? I tried to remove the BreezeController attribute and add these
[ODataActionFilter, JsonFormatter] but i have another error (The action 'Posts' on controller 'Posts' ..... cannot support querying)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad. The [BreezeController] attribute was too aggressive in removing ambient action filters; it apparently removed the filter responsible for the [Authorize] attribute. I have a fix that is currently under review.

The "[ODataActionFilter, JsonFormatter]" formula didn't suffer from this problem because it didn't remove any existing filters.  Of course that was a problem too. **If you used the new  ASP.NET MVC SPA template ... and I think you are! ... then its QueryFilterProvider conflicted with our ODataActionFilter** ... which is why we invented the [BreezeController] attribute and why, I think, that you're getting the error about not supporting querying. Can you confirm that you built your app from that SPA template?

Btw ... what 'Posts' action are you talking about? The "Breeze.MVC4WebApiClientSample" does not have such an action.

In any case, we expect to have the [BreezeController] attribute working properly with [Authorize] very soon.

Comment: We fixed it today. Should be fine as of v.0.82.1

Comment: Hi Ward, sorry for mixing up the sample project with my own project. You're right, my own project is created using the SPA template.

Anyway, i updated to 0.82.1 and it works now, thanks a lot!

Comment: Hey, Ward.  This still seems to be an issue for me with version 1.4.11.  I have a custom attribute which inherits from AuthorizeAttribute.  On a standard controller, attributing an action works fine.  On a breeze controller it never calls the OnAuthorization() overload.

Answer (score 1):

As of breeze v0.82.1, this should now be fixed.  The BreezeController attribute will no longer cause the removall of any authorization attributes.